# Missing :id routes on resource creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My `rake routes` after creating the resource :articles says I should get:

```
Prefix Verb      URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
articles  GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
          POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
new_article  GET /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
article  GET     /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
         PATCH   /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
         PUT     /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
         DELETE  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
    root GET     /                            welcome#index
```

However my routes are always missing those with :id in them.

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
articles POST     /articles(.:format)      articles#create
new_articles  GET /articles/new(.:format)  articles#new
edit_articles GET /articles/edit(.:format) articles#edit
          GET     /articles(.:format)      articles#show
          PATCH   /articles(.:format)      articles#update
          PUT     /articles(.:format)      articles#update
          DELETE  /articles(.:format)      articles#destroy
     root GET     /                        welcome#index
```

Comment: could you post your routes file?

Comment: Make sure you are using resources :articles and not resource :articles

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you have added to the routes:

```
resource :articles
```

instead of:

```
resources :article
```

Singular resource is used when you don't have to provide `id` to identify resource. Ie.: when you operate on current user's profile: `/profile`

Comment: It's a subtle difference and something a beginner Rails developer would miss.

Comment: Thank you, its an embarrassingly small change that I can't believe I never picked up on.